# Combining maxLength with wrap_content on Android TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have a needs to limit the length of a textview to a certain number and then make the text wrap. Unfortunately using maxLength will only "crop" the text and won't make it wrapping like it should be even when using `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. How to achieve this feature?

Comment: Can you post your XML layout code?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your text view,

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

And add this,

`android:minEms="..."`

Or

`android:minWidth="..."`